# correct way to iterate over sections in msWord in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, header, sections

## 1. situation

In word, I want to iterate over sections, then print the text, and text in TextBox in header of the last page in every sections in VBA. Where the section is seperated by a `section breaks` to start a `Next Page` because the header has different information and numbering style just like common books do.

I made a simple [`demo.docx`](https://github.com/retsyo/misc_bugs/blob/main/demo.docx) for testing , which has 3 sections

- 1st section has 2 pages, and on last page, the text is "Header of section 1", and the textbox says "Current page II, total page 2"
- 2nd section has 3 pages, and on last page, the text is "Section 2", and the textbox says "section 2, 3/3"
- 3rd section has 4 pages, and on last page, the text is "Sec 3", and the textbox says "4/4 in section 3"

## 2. expected

The expected output by code in following is

```
pure text: Header of section 1

text in textbox: Current page II, total page 2
 
====
pure text: Section 2

text in textbox:  section 2, 3/3
 
====
pure text: Sec 3

text in textbox:  4/4 in section 3
 
====
```

and the corrected output can be made by https://www.wps.com/

## 3. bad result I got till now

However msWord( Yes, I know we can't save the code in a `docx` file) prints out

```
pure text: Section 2

text in textbox:  section 2, 1/5
 
====
pure text: Sec 3

text in textbox:  1/4 in section 3
 
====
pure text: Sec 3

text in textbox:  1/4 in section 3
 
====
```

## 4. need help

Any way to fix it? Thanks

## 5. the code I am using

```
Sub ConcatenateHeaderText5()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim sec As Section
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim shape As shape
    Dim headerText As String
    

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    Dim pages(1 To 3) As Integer
    pages(1) = 2
    pages(2) = 2 + 3
    pages(3) = 2 + 3 + 4
    
    idxSection = 1

    For Each sec In doc.Sections

        txtInTexbox = ""
        
        Set rng = Selection.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=0, Name:=pages(idxSection))
        
        Set rng = rng.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        
        
        txtPure = Trim(rng.Text)
        

        For Each shape In rng.ShapeRange

            If shape.Type = msoTextBox Then
                txtInTexbox = txtInTexbox & shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & " "
            End If
        Next shape

        
        idxSection = idxSection + 1
    
    
        Debug.Print "pure text: " & txtPure
        Debug.Print "text in textbox: " & txtInTexbox
        Debug.Print "===="
        
    Next sec
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good example of how to ask a question. It also proactively includes a sample template for the respondent to refer to. I will want to help people like this, and I will try.

Comment: I don't understand  this, why :  *the corrected output can be made by https://www.wps.com/*

Comment: I don't understand why `WPS` can produce the right output too. But that is not really true always. To be frankly, actually I am using `python+pywin32` via `COM` instead of `VBA`. The python code has a similiar structure as above VBA code. If I associate `DOCX` with `WPS`, open `demo.docx` with `WPS` firstly, then my python code uses `WPS` and gives right result. However if I launch `WPS` only but do not open `demo.docx`, python code uses `WPS` too but gives the wrong result produced by `msWord`. Wrong result is produced also if I do not launch `WPS` but let python code do that.

Comment: If I bundle DOCX to msWord, my python code always gives the wrong result in the following 3 situation: 1) I run msWord and open `demo.docx`; 2)I run msWord only without any file is opened; 3)no msWord is run till my python code opens one

Answer (score 0):

## The Ultimate Solution

[download .docm file to test](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uC4p_ksWDQQg00pF-Xk_-TiTf4F8Q_Wv/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106108182093734588005&rtpof=true&sd=true)

[How to download the .docm *(the MS Word document file with VBA code)* file from Google Drive.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yVlDI8JN8U&t=53s)

### Concept

The problem is that iterating through **Headers**, not just [**Sections**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.sections), and only [**Section**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.section) objects have the [**Headers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.section.headers) property. So the key is to use the [**NextStoryRange**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.nextstoryrange) property of the **[StoryRanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.storyranges)**/**Range** object to iterate through the Header type StoryRange objects one by one to get into the textbox in every Header and [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.select) the [TextRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.textframe.textrange) to recalculate the [Fields' Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.field.result).

### [Now Rrint Result](https://youtube.com/live/lmnPsugsSiU?feature=share)

Now Whether it's 32-bit MS Word 2016 or 64-bit 2013 or 64-bit 2019, we can output consistent results:

```
pure text: Header of section 1

text in textbox: Current page II, total page 2

====
pure text: Section 2

text in textbox:  section 2, 5/5

====
pure text: Sec 3

text in textbox:  4/4 in section 3

====
```

I also found that **different MS Word versions probably take different values for Fields, resulting in different results for the same code**. For more details, read the next section.*

- *it is supposed that by default, 2019  is taking the first-page number( just like the @oyster 's result ), while 2016 and 2013 are the total numbers of pages or the last-page number. If without method **Select** to recalculate the Result of the Field **{ PAGE  * MERGEFORMAT }**, it will be this.*

### Final Code

```vb
Sub ConcatenateHeaderText5()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim sec As Section
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Dim txtInTexbox As String
    Dim txtPure As String
    
    Dim StryRng As Range

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set originalPosition = Selection.Range.Duplicate

    doc.Fields.Update

    Rem iterates over all sections in the doc already.
    For Each sec In doc.Sections

        If StryRng Is Nothing Then 'First Section object's Header range
            Set StryRng = ThisDocument.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory)
        Else
            Set StryRng = StryRng.NextStoryRange 'ie. next Section's Header
        End If
        
        
        txtPure = VBA.Trim(StryRng.Text)
        
'        'remove the last chr(13) (symbol for paragraph) if need
'        txtPure = VBA.Left(txtPure, VBA.Len(txtPure) - 1)
        
        'go to the last page of the section
        Set rng = sec.Range.Paragraphs(sec.Range.Paragraphs.Count).Range
        rng.Select
        
        'do this to refresh the Fields in the textbox in the header
        StryRng.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
        
        txtInTexbox = StryRng.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        
        Debug.Print "pure text: " & txtPure
        Debug.Print "text in textbox: " & txtInTexbox
        Debug.Print "===="
        
    Next sec
   
   
    originalPosition.Select
    doc.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range

End Sub
```

## Previous Experience Process

Test my code first please :
*it did the result in MS Word:*

- I have not used WPS and Python, and I do not know how they run the code. So you have to convert the code I gave you into a code or a way that it can be executed and presented. So maybe you try it in MS Word first.
  This is print in both **32-bit MS Word 2016** and **64-bit 2013**:

```
pure text: Header of section 1
text in textbox: Current page II, total page 2
 
====
pure text: Section 2
text in textbox:  section 2, 5/5
 
====
pure text: Sec 3
text in textbox:  4/4 in section 3
 
====
```

The sample you gave us is actually :

- 1st section has **2** pages, and on last page, the text is "Header of section 2", and the textbox says "Current page **II**, total page **2**" *( sorry about the previous bug )*
- 2nd section has **5** pages, and on last page, the text is "Section 2", and the textbox says "section 2, **5/5**"
- 3rd section has 4 pages, and on last page, the text is "Sec 3", and the textbox says "4/4 in section 3"

However, in **64-bit 2019**, running the same code will print:

```vb
pure text: Header of section 1
text in textbox: Current page I, total page 3
 
====
pure text: Section 2
text in textbox:  section 2, 1/4
 
====
pure text: Sec 3
text in textbox:  1/4 in section 3
 
====
```

[This is my .docm file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uC4p_ksWDQQg00pF-Xk_-TiTf4F8Q_Wv/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106108182093734588005&rtpof=true&sd=true) based on your demo.docx.

[How to download the .docm *(the MS Word document file with VBA code)* file from Google Drive.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yVlDI8JN8U&t=53s)

```vb
Sub ConcatenateHeaderText5()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim sec As Section
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim shape As shape
    Dim headerText As String
    
    
    Rem using Section's Index property rather than this variabel to get the inx of a section 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.section.index?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dzh-TW%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm156827772)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue
    'Dim idxSection As Integer
    
    Dim txtInTexbox As String
    Dim txtPure As String

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set originalPosition = Selection.Range.Duplicate
'    Selection.HomeKey wdStory, wdMove ' update the fields
    
    
    Rem why do you use this variable pages?
    
'    Dim pages(1 To 3) As Integer
'    pages(1) = 2
'    pages(2) = 2 + 3
'    pages(3) = 2 + 3 + 4
'

    'idxSection = 1

    Rem using this For Each ... Next statement you just are able to iterate over all sections in the doc already.
    For Each sec In doc.Sections
    
'        txtInTexbox = ""
        
        Rem You've already done it the right way with For Each statement, so don't use something like this(ie. Selection.GoTo) again to do it
'        Set rng = Selection.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=0, Name:=pages(idxSection))
        
        Rem You've already used the For Each statement, should make the most of it.
        Rem use section object sec rather than subscripting the collection Sections to access its elements (ie. Sections(1))
        'Set rng = rng.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        
        Rem this will change the page count, so we'll use "Set rng = originalPosition" and call the procedure restoreHeaderView at the end to restore it. by the present, I don't know why.
        Set rng = sec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range

        txtPure = VBA.Trim(rng.Text)
        
        'remove the last chr(13) (symbol for paragraph)
        txtPure = VBA.Left(txtPure, VBA.Len(txtPure) - 1)
        
        Set rng = originalPosition 'Prevent the number of pages from being changed, which will affect the following readings
        
        Rem you just want the end page number, not To Iterate all of them.
        Rem and Only Section object got the property Headers
        Rem so Every section got a textbox, and the text in the textbox you want is already a field of the page, So we pick corresonding one.
        Rem You should first understand the characteristics of the Section and Header objects.
'        For Each shape In rng.ShapeRange
            Set shape = sec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes(sec.Index)
            If shape.Type = msoTextBox Then
                'txtInTexbox = txtInTexbox & shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & " "
                txtInTexbox = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & " "
            Else
                MsgBox "There is no textbox in the header of this section!", vbExclamation
                'txtInTexbox = txtInTexbox & shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & " "
            End If

'        Next shape

        
        'idxSection = idxSection + 1
    
    
        Debug.Print "pure text: " & txtPure
        Debug.Print "text in textbox: " & txtInTexbox
        Debug.Print "===="
        
    Next sec
   
    Selection.SetRange originalPosition.Start, originalPosition.End
    
    restoreHeaderView doc, doc.Sections(1)
End Sub

Sub restoreHeaderView(doc As Document, sec As Section)
        Dim sectionRange As Range, pageNum As Integer
        Set sectionRange = doc.Range(sec.Range.Paragraphs(sec.Range.Paragraphs.Count).Range.End - 1, sec.Range.Paragraphs(sec.Range.Paragraphs.Count).Range.End - 1)
        ' Get the page number of the current section
        pageNum = sectionRange.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, I have not noticed that the [section 2  is considered as 5 pages by winword](https://github.com/retsyo/misc_bugs/blob/main/demo_opened_with_winword.png), so there are **2** + **5** + 4 = 11 pages. However this should not be a problem for code to read informations on the last pages of every sections. However, 1) your code [only read the information on first page in every sections](https://github.com/retsyo/misc_bugs/blob/main/vba_result_winword.png);

Comment: 2) the file has be changed to [**3** +5+4=12 pages after the VBA code runs in winword](https://github.com/retsyo/misc_bugs/blob/main/demo_after_run_vba_winword.png). Btw, I am using pre-installed Microsoft Office Home and Student 2019 for windows 10 64bits on my laptop

Comment: As for `WPS`, there are [2 + **3** + 4 =9 pages](https://github.com/retsyo/misc_bugs/blob/main/demo_opened_with_wps2.png). Your code only [read the header on first page on every sections](https://github.com/retsyo/misc_bugs/blob/main/vba_result_wps.png)

Comment: @oyster ok, I've fixed the bug which changes the page count when reading the Section range.  The download link is the same. Please try again. THANKS.

Comment: @oyster *...read the header on first page on every sections ..* not really, if you run in VBA in MS Word then should know it is not only the first page's result, just like the result I posted in my answer. Since you are reading the pages with **Fields**, I don't think it should affect the correctness of executing the code.

Comment: @oyster It's Done! Details of my answer are updated. All that remains is to wait and see the results of your test with WPS and Python. Good Luck.

Comment: So bad. winword still says "pure text: Header of section 1
text in textbox: Current page I, total page 3
 
====
pure text: Section 2
text in textbox:  section 2, 1/5
 
====
pure text: Sec 3
text in textbox:  1/4 in section 3
 
===="

Comment: and WPS says "pure text: Header of section 1 
text in textbox: Current page I, total page 2
 
==== 
pure text: Section 2 
text in textbox:  section 2, I/2 
 
==== 
pure text: Sec 3 
text in textbox:  I/2 in section 3 
 
====

Comment: Then I can not help, I used 3 computers, 3 different versions of Word debugging printed out as described in my answer (wait to add the actual test video) I do not have another computer on hand to test, perhaps you follow my fumbling, I have used the object or principle of trying again. I also continue to perform and monitor the error detection line by line to break the original bottleneck. Anyway, the object in the header is linked to the chapter, and in your case used the Textboxs and Feilds, it will become more complicated.

Comment: @oyster Is your problem solved? If not, try updating all the Fields in the document before running the code search. `doc.Fields.Update` I do not have the environment to test, it will be necessary to ask you to test. Thanks. The code in my answer has also been updated( the file shared with you, too.).